# Meaning of "Lift" in "International sanctions lifted"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I want to know is it correct that "Lift" sometimes means to be "stop" as [Wendy Sherman](https://youtu.be/2bvlG74e0Kg?t=531) claimed in 2016 about the usage of that word in "International sanctions lifted"?

Google and almost everywhere that I have read ever, its meaning is "raise up, hoist, boost up, pick up, remove, etc. "

Comment: well, if the sanctions are "removed", doesn't it mean that they are stopped?

Comment: Presumably _International sanctions lifted_ is  'headlinese' for _...have been lifted_, with _lift_ in the sense of _remove_, as @fev says.

Comment: @fev, I think No, if  so why Wendy Sherman explains that "Lift" means "stop" i.e. we *stop* imposing new sanctions but we don't *remove* the old sanctions!!

Comment: @KateBunting: I thought as you but but it is not true. compare these two: "stop from imposing new sanctions" vs "removing old sanctions".

Comment: @C.F.G: "Lift"  means to stop imposing any kind of sanctions, whether old or new. In the same way that you LIFT a fence that obstructs a passage.

Comment: Your link is to a Wikipedia article on Ms Sherman. I couldn't find the passage you refer to.

Comment: @KateBunting: I find that interview: [see this](https://youtu.be/2bvlG74e0Kg?t=531)

Comment: I hear her say that "_Lift_ in English means _suspend_ though to the Iranians it means _remove_", and that they would suspend certain sanctions but not others.

Comment: You are right but "Lift" mostly means "remove" and not "suspend" isn't?   and she is the only person that argue like this.

Comment: Is the question then **(1)** what is the connection between the literal meaning of *lift* and its metaphorical use in the contexts of this kind, **or (2)** whether this metaphorical meaning includes stopping temporarily, as well as permanently? If (2), that should be made clear within the question; those who voted to close it as a duplicate obviously interpreted it as (1).

Comment: @jsw29: I am not sure but I think  (2) is more close to my question.